# How to update the form based on a crosstab

Tags: ms-access

I suppose the solution is at http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs,_forms_and_updating (frequently mentioned by user Fionnuala)
but unfortunatelly the images do not show. Can anyone give me similar examples? I find the solution so useful but cannot understand it well enough.

Comment: You talk about refreshing the data in the form, or changing values by form editing? If first, you can find the code at the end of link you referred . If second - it's not possible. You should use temporary table instead of crosstab query.

Comment: That is downright embarrassing. I guess I have the images somewhere. Give me a minute or two.